# How can I find the VAT Nr of an organisation by looking at a money transfer?

Tags: bank-account, limited-liability-company, vat

I have an app in multiple appstores (ios, android, windows).
I have received money from transactions in these stores, and the VAT is taken care of by the stores.
Now I have to do my tax administration and I need to fill in the VAT id of the companies that paid me.

I am very dissapointed that none of the 3 platforms give you some kind of self-billed invoice with all the proper details for the payouts and the sub-organisations, all located in Ireland, that performed them. You need to create them yourselve it seems.

Also for all 3 platforms I can't find a page with the official VAT id for the company that did the payout. I somehow also have to look them up myself, but all I have to go on is the bank account that performed the transaction.

So far my best efforts have resulted in the following assumptions:

- Payouts registred by my bank as coming from "Google Payment Ireland Limited" from bank account nr IE29 CITI 99005124179036 belong to VAT ID [IE 6388047V] which, [according to the VAT registration](http://www.vat-lookup.co.uk/verify/vat_check.php/VATNumber/IE6388047V) belongs to "GOOGLE IRELAND LIMITED".
- Payouts registred by my bank as coming from "Apple Inc" from bank account nr GB29 DEUT 40508124517700 belong to VAT ID [IE 9700053D] which, [according to the VAT registration](http://www.vat-lookup.co.uk/verify/vat_check.php/VATNumber/IE9700053D/CompanyName/APPLE+DISTRIBUTION+INTERNATIONAL) belongs to "APPLE DISTRIBUTION INTERNATIONAL LTD".
- Payouts registred by my bank as coming from "Microsoft corporation" from bank account nr IE32 BOFA 99006156997013 belongs to VAT ID [IE8256796U] which [according to the VAT registration](http://www.vat-lookup.co.uk/verify/vat_check.php/VATNumber/IE8256796U) belongs to "MICROSOFT IRELAND OPERATIONS LIMITED".

Who can help me confirm these assumptions and help me in finding the proper way to find the correct VAT id nrs for the organisations that performed the transactions?

Sidenote: when I receive a bill for Azure services (also Microsoft), they do include a VAT nr [NL806702242B01] belonging to Microsoft Ireland Operations Ltd. But the sub-company that handles azure bills might be a total different sub-company that handles microsoft store payments. How to tell..

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the Apple part. It's the same information as what I've been using for many years, ever since they "moved" from Luxembourg to Ireland.

As for Google, the bank account indeed belongs to Google Payment Ireland Limited. But to my best knowledge (found using a certain search engine) their VAT number is IE 3463004VH (confirmed using [this tool](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/)). The VAT number you mention belongs to a different entity, without "Payment" in the name. It's the one that handles Google AdSense payments.

Google actually does provide payment receipts. Have a look at the transactions in your Google Wallet Merchant Account. The bad news is that the receipts state yet another Google entity: Google Payment Ltd, London, UK. (plain negligence, IMHO). The good news is that the payment number matches the number in the bank statement. So I'm going for the Irish entity, otherwise I'd have to start paying VAT in the UK.

I don't know anything about Microsoft.

Comment: Indeed I could find payment receipts from Google by going to the Google payment center (www.pay.google.com). I had to navigate to "subscription & services"- "Google play apps" - click on "view transactions" and scroll down to a clickable entry with the prefix "automatic payment". Here I found the payment receipt (not when downloading the report for that month what I expected). The info in my payment receipts actually does match up (unlike yours), it mentiones Google Payment Ireland Ltd. and the VAT nr 3463004VH.